# Effect sizes for post-hoc paired comparisons in one-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, effect-size, post-hoc

Is there any alternative (like Cohen's d in t-test) to report about effect sizes for post-hoc paired comparisons in a one-way ANOVA (3 factor levels, correlated samples)?.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can test a contrast, which gives you a $t$-ratio:

$t=\displaystyle\frac{\hat{\Psi}_j}{\hat{\sigma}_\psi} = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{p}c_j\bar{Y}_j}{\sqrt{MS_{error}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{p}\frac{c^2_j}{} }}$,

where $p$ is the number of levels in your categorical variable and $c_j$ is the contract weight for the $j^{th}$ level. Then convert the $t$ to $Cohen's\;d$.

Alternatively, you can test a contrast $\bar{Y}_{Max} - \bar{Y}_{Min}$ and compute $d_{Max}$.

Comment: Is this implemented in some R package?